# BinaryObjectException: Cannot find schema for object with compact footer

Tags: java, caching, ignite

This is the scenario: I deploy my web application to two Tomcat servers, and I use Apache Ignite to cluster web sessions. The load balancer is put in the round robin fashion.

The software I use are:

- JDK 1.8.0_66
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.68
- Apache Ignite 1.6.0
- Crossroads load balancer version 2.65

Below is the data I put into the session:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SessionData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int counter;

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public SessionData() {
    }
}
```

And I can verify that the two applications do share the same data, and everything works perfectly.

Then I update the session data class to:

```java
public class SessionData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int counter;
    private String ip;

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }
    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public SessionData() {
    }
}
```

And I deploy the new web application to one of the servers. Now when I refresh the web page which will in turn read and update the counter in the session data, I keep getting the following error from both servers, and the page never loads.

```
ERROR - root                       - Failed to update web session: null
class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Cannot find schema for object with compact footer [typeId=-2056860774, schemaId=1954049593]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.getOrCreateSchema(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1721)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.<init>(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:278)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.<init>(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:177)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.<init>(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:156)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:298)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal(BinaryMarshaller.java:109)
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionV2.unmarshal(WebSessionV2.java:336)
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionV2.getAttribute(WebSessionV2.java:200)
```

I believe this is a common senario. Imagine there are dozens of nodes in the cluster, and we need to redeploy an updated version of web application to all of the nodes one after another. And during the process of redeployment, this issue will surface, and the user will suffer from it.

Wonder if this is a real problem for Apache Ignite, or due to my misconfiguration/misunderstanding? And if it is problem, is there any work-around? Or I have to shut down all the servers in the worst case; and if we use a persistent store, do we need to purge all the data in the persistent store?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the reasons, but this looks like incorrect behavior. Created a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3194

As a workaround you can try to disable compact footers. To do this, add the following to you Ignite configuration:

```
<property name="binaryConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration">
        <property name="compactFooter" value="false"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: Disabling compact footers does help! Thanks @Valentin. Wonder if you could explain a little bit more why/how this configuration does the trick please, and is there any side effect to the clustered application with compact footers disabled? Thank you.

Comment: For the record, [IGNITE-9843](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-9843) appears to be the same problem as this one, and a fix for it has been merged into Ignite's master branch. It looks like the fix will be included in Ignite 2.8 when that is released.